# how to switch off chatter feed tracking for a single contact record

Tags: chatter-feed-tracking

how to switch off chatter feed tracking for a single contact record?

I need to change some info in a contact record and it shouldn't show anywhere in chatter that I have updated that value. It might even be an account name.

Is this possible? can someone help here?

Comment: I think going to chatter settings and disabling and then enabling will work.Also you can stop field Tracking for that field and then again enable field tracking.

Comment: will this not disable the whole chatter itself? other users will be working and it shouldnt impact the changes that they are doing

Comment: Well we can disable this and make the change when they are off work.and I am not asking for whole disable of chatter.Only lets disable field tracking for that field .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have said - you'd have to disable and then reenable chatter for whole object or modify the field tracking. You can do it outside business hours if it's some kind of data fix.

(let's ignore for a while the fact that the whole purpose of audit fields is to track history and you might get in trouble during audit even if it's a valid data fix ;))

You can also run the data fix, then find the Chatter entries created by you & delete them. At least it worked for me when I had to delete one user's entry created from field history tracking, **you might be best trying it out first in a sandbox**.

```
SELECT Id, Name,  
(SELECT Id, Ttile, Body 
    FROM Feeds
    WHERE Type = 'TrackedChange' AND CreatedById = :UserInfo.getUserId() 
        AND CreatedDate = TODAY
)
FROM My_Object__c
```

Loop through the results, build List of Ids for `FeedItem`s you want to delete and fire!

Comment: nice will try that as well

Answer (score 1):

Create an after insert trigger that deletes the feeditem if the parent id matches that contact.

For extensibility, have a custom field called "disallow chatter" on that object.

Comment: Field tracking inserts happen somehow after the transaction actually commits (that's why we can never generate entries in `*History` tables inside test method). I suspect it will be same with these ones. So it could work but as @future and then you'd have to distinguish between "admin update" and "regular user's update". Plus it means you need to deploy some code to prod, test it etc. while it sounds like one-off data fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on a per record basis but you could disable tracking for that one field which you are about to change, and then turn it back on.

Click Your Name | Setup | Customize | Chatter | Feed Tracking.
Select an object.
Here you can either disable feed tracking for Contact or alternatively disable tracking on the field you're about to change, and then turn it back on.

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/collab_feed_tracking.htm

Comment: oh ok @techtrekker is it possible to disable it for contact object's account field?

Comment: I'm not around a computer now, but you could just take a look if it is available to deselect. Alternatively just turn it off temporarily for the Contact object.